# Can't establish a database connection

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, hosting

I'm new to creating a WordPress site so every time I run into an issue I'm not sure how to troubleshoot it. I just finished uploading my site to a sub-domain I created. I already created and imported a database and added the DB_name, DB_user and DB_password into the wp_config.php file. However, when I got to test.nextgennow.com (my site) it gives me "Error establising a database connection."

Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

This could be a variety of things, assuming the database service is actually up and running correctly, and has your account configured.

A good place to check for any and all errors that you get would be the error log for the web service.  This may give you more detail as to what the actual error is.

If you can check the error logs for the database service itself if you can access them, these too may help.

Check that you have entered your credentials exactly correctly, no case errors, rogue spaces or punctuation at the end between the quotes.

If you have shell access try and connect to the database using those credentials (or with a tool like php_myadmin).

It could be a variety of other issues, but without any knowledge of your setup it's pretty difficult to help you diagnose, hopefully one of the above suggestions will be of some help.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I'm assuming that I do have access to the error log for the web service since it is my hosting account but I'm not sure where I could find that.

I checked to make sure that I entered everything correctly and it seems like I did.

Comment: Obviously I cannot tell you that, but I would imagine it is with your sites access logs.  I would assume that your hosting provider would provide you access to these, possibly best to check with their technical support/documentation.